# Sorting the api response A-Z/Z-A with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to sort my api response based on what the user selects whether A-Z or Z-A. I am using React Redux and axios for calling and getting the api.

My code is below

The search action look like this
***search.action.js***

```
export const fetchProducts = text => dispatch => {
  console.log("Called from ", text);

  const token = userService.getToken();

  const api = `/Search?searchString=${text}`;

  axios
    .get(apiBaseUrl + api, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })

    .then(res => {
      console.log("hello", api);
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PRODUCTS,
          payload: res
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
      }
    });
};
```

***searchReducer***

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        text: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case PAGINATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        pagination: { ...state.pagination, currentPage: action.payload }
      };

    case FETCH_PRODUCTS:
      console.log(
        "action",
        action,
        "actionPayload",
        action.payload,
        "state",
        state
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        totalRecords: action.payload.length
      };

    case LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };

    case PRODUCT_DETAILS:
      console.log("Product Details -- Action", action);
      console.log("Product Details -- payload", action.payload);
      console.log("Product Details -- state", state);

      return {
        ...state,
        product: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        totalRecords: action.payload.length
      };

    default:
      // console.log("Default action");
      return state;
  }
};
```

Similarly the jsx code look like below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Rating from "./rating";
import "./test.css";
import { Spinner, Collapse, Card, CardBody } from "reactstrap";
import { detailsProduct } from "../../../_actions/product.details.action";
import { ProductDetails, DoctorProductLocation } from "../../../locations";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { setLoading } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import Select from "react-select";
// import { fetchProducts } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
// import { detailsProduct } from "../../../_actions/product.details.action";

function onClickHandler(id) {
  console.log("calling Details Product", id);
  detailsProduct(id);
}

export default function SingleSearchResult(props) {
  console.log("PROPS FROM SINGLE SEARCH", props);
  let result = props.result;

  //Collapse For External
  const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setCollapse(!collapse);

  const loading = () => <Spinner color="success" />;

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="s130">
        <div className="col-lg">
          <div className="container">
            <Loader
              type="ThreeDots"
              color="#00BFFF"
              height="100"
              width="100"
              timeout={1000}
            ></Loader>
            {result.type === "Internal" ? (
              <Link
                value={result.productid}
                to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
                onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)} 
              >
                <h3>{result.title}</h3>
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <a onClick={toggle} target="_blank">
                <h3 style={{ color: "blue" }}>{result.title}</h3>
              </a>
            )}

            {result.type == "Article" ? <p>by {result.author}</p> : ""}
            <Rating rating={result.rating} />
          </div>
          {result.type === "Internal" ? (
            <Link
              className="iUh30"
              to={DoctorProductLocation.path}
              onClick={() => onClickHandler(result.productid)}
            >
              <a className="iUh30">{result.url}</a>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            //Try With OnClick Function
            <Collapse isOpen={collapse}>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  Source:
                  <a className="iUh30" href={result.url} target="_blank">
                    <a>{result.url}</a>
                  </a>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
              <Card style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
                <CardBody>
                  <a
                    href={result.url + "subscribe"}
                    style={{ color: "blue" }}
                    target="_blank"
                  >
                    Subscribe
                  </a>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>

              <br></br>
            </Collapse>
          )}

          {/* <p>{ result.description } <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="{ result.url }">See more</a></p> */}
          <p className="rank">Visited {result.rank} times</p>
          {/* <br /> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The searchUI Component where I am using sorting and other filters are as follows. P.S. I am using reactjs select library.

```
import React from "react";
import queryString from "query-string";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SearchResult from "./search-results";
import { results } from "../../../_actions/data/result";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
import SearchBar from "./search-bar";
import { fetchProducts, searchProduct } from "../../../_actions/search.action";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

class SearchResultContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).q;
    this.props.searchProduct(query);
    this.props.fetchProducts(query);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
    // if (nextProps.query !== this.props.query) {
    //   this.setState({ query: nextProps.query });
    //   return this.searchRepositories(nextProps.query);
    // }
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props;
    console.log("PROS", this.props);

    const companies = [
      {
        label: "Example",
        value: "https://www.example.de"
      },
      {
        label: "Orange",
        value: "https://www.orange.com"
      },
      {
        label: "Apple",
        value: "https://www.apple.com"
      }
    ];
    const Order = [
      {
        label: "A-Z"
      },
      {
        label: "Z-A"
      }
    ];
    return loading ? (
      <div class="row"></div>
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-2" />
          <div className="col-sm-8">
            <SearchBar />
            <Select options={companies}></Select>
            <Select placeholder="Order..." options={Order}></Select>
            <br></br>
            <div class="row">
              <Loader
                type="ThreeDots"
                color="#00BFFF"
                height="100"
                width="100"
                timeout={100}
              ></Loader>
              <SearchResult />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-2" />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.product.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { searchProduct, fetchProducts })(
  SearchResultContainer
);
```

For any search query the result UI look like this

[image]

Comment: You are saying you are trying to sort the response A-Z/Z-A. Where in your code are you trying to do that?

Comment: just add sort action with direction in payload - sort in reducer - remember to return new object, not in place sort .... details in redux? why??

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin Please check the edits. I have put more code where I am using ```<Select```